# jquery ui dialog is not opening on button click when autoopen is set to false

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i m using asp.net forms this page i m working on has a masterpage it works great when autoopen is false but when autofalse is true i dont know why it doesnt work. code is ..

```
$(document).ready(function () {

         $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            appendTo: "form",

            show: {
                effect: "fade",
                duration: 1000
            },
                             hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            },

            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $("[id*=btnmsgOk]").click();
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

 });
```

and i call this function by this..

```
$('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function () {
             $("#dialog").dialog("open");
          });
```

but it dosent work.

Comment: Have you tried to put this function in `$('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function () {
             $("#dialog").dialog("open");
          });` inside `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: yes in tried that but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried following, it is working fine. Please note that , you have missed to put **#** in jquery selector. It should be `$('#<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').click...`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    appendTo: "form",

    show: {
      effect: "fade",
      duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "explode",
      duration: 1000
    },

    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
        $("[id*=btnmsgOk]").click();
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });

});
$("#clicktoopen").click(function() {
  $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<div id="dialog">DIV</div>
<button id="btnmsgOk" value="btn" style="display:none">Ok</button>
<button id="clicktoopen" value="click">Click</button>
```

Comment: i pasted your code and it ran just once for unknown reason. i did put # selector as you suggested.

Comment: i just tested it with a div click then it worked but its not working with asp.net button click.

Comment: @BRBHARDWAJ Have you tried `$('#<%=btnSave.ClientID %>')`? If so, please paste the error , that you got in browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Important thing you should know while using Jquery is PostBack property
When postback occurse JQuery code will get its original values..
So you should prevent postback to see the functionality of it..

e.preventDefaults();

i used animations which delays forms to be visible so i wasnt able to see dialog but i fixed it myself. thanks for everybody who responded to it.